# PHP/MySQL Using Variables and INSERT INTO syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pass variable values to a MySQL database table. I am using a PDO to get access to the database, and am able to echo the variable values that I want to insert to my browser. The only thing I can think of is that my syntax is wrong. I am clearly a novice at using PHP/MySQL.

I am not getting any errors. The info isn't going into my table. What am I doing wrong?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO testquiz (version, points, passing_percent, gained_score, username, email, quiz_title, date)
VALUES ('$version', $points, $passing_percent, $gained_score, '$username', '$email', '$quiz_title', CURDATE() )";
```

Query to create table:

MySQL CREATE TABLE Query:

```
    CREATE TABLE testquiz (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    version TEXT,
    points INT,
    passing_percent DOUBLE,
    gained_score DOUBLE,
    username TEXT,
    email TEXT,
    quiz_title TEXT,
    date DATE NOT NULL
    ) DEFAULTCHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: Post your complete code.

Comment: are all fields strings? If not, do not put quotes around those fields.
My guess is something like `VALUES ($version, $points, ...` etc.

Comment: Updated original question with appropriate quotes for variables. Thank you.

Comment: Do not put quotes around `int` and `double` values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using PDO, the generally accepted practice is to use prepared statements for SQL, which essentially are a method used to sanitize your string input.

If your database connection object is `$dbo` then it would usually go like this.

Create a prepared statement by calling the prepare method on your database connection object:

```
$sql = $dbo->prepare("INSERT INTO testquiz (version, points, passing_percent, gained_score, username, email, quiz_title, date)
VALUES (:version, :points, :passing_percent, :gained_score, :username, :email, :quiz_title, CURDATE())");
```

As you can see, instead of passing in the variables I want for the values directly, I've created placeholders. Then, call the execute method on the $sql obect and pass the values in for the placeholders as key-value pairs in an array.

```
$sql->execute(array(":version" => $version, ":points" => $points, ":passing_percent" => $passing_percent, ":gained_score" => $gained_score, ":username" => $username, ":email" => $email, ":quiz_title" => $quiz_title));
```

This code passes in the values you define instead of the placeholders, and it properly escapes and sanitizes the variables you pass in for security, while executing your INSERT statement.

https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: Someone give this guy a vote. I don't have enough rep. This immediately fixed my issue. I love you.

Comment: Does this work if I have the variables being assigned from $_POST values?

Comment: Yes, it works with any value or variable you pass in. However, it's usually good practice to do some error-check besides sanitizing, so it may be best for security and readibility to assign the $_POST values to variables first.

Comment: OK cool. That's what I've done so far, which is where the variables in my initial post were derived from. Still not working on my live server though...

Comment: Maybe you should check to make sure your connection string on your PDO object is correct. And try surrounding the column and table names in backticks (`)

Comment: Just posted my full code on this page with a better description of my issue. Had to clean it before I could post it all here.

Answer (score 0):

Change the insert statement to the below format and try.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO testquiz (version, points, passing_percent, gained_score, username, email, quiz_title, date)
VALUES ('".$version."', '".$points."', '".$passing_percent."', '".$gained_score."', '".$username."', '".$email."', '".$quiz_title."', CURDATE())";
```

Comment: This had no effect on my results. Thanks for trying but my table is still blank after execution.